# PHP fetchAll on JOIN

Tags: php, sql, join, fetchall

When I try to fetch from a query on a single table I get an associated array where Key is a name of column. But when I try to `JOIN` another table's columns on a query I get an array which only contains a key 'row' and a string value which looks like
`(value1,value2,value3,...,valueN)`, without column names.
I need to get associated array (I use `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` for that) as an output, but I get a string

example of my query:

```
SELECT (item.id, item.category_id, item_category.letter, item_category.name_eng) 
FROM item
LEFT JOIN item_category ON item_category.letter = item.category_id
WHERE item.id = :id
```

I get this from that query:

```
Array
(
    [row] => (2314,"B","B","Name")
)
```

I would like to get:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2314,
    [category_id] => "B",
    [letter] => "B",
    [name_eng] => "Name"
)
```

I've tried to explode an output string with ',' separator, but it's a dumb idea cuz if i got ',' in table data I split it into different array elements

How do I get an assoc array from that?

Comment: fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) gives you **associative array**. What is giving you string is **your own code** and we cannot know which.

Comment: $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result) gives me an output which i discribed above, [row] => (...,...,...)

Comment: then it is not a PDOStatement but something else

Comment: public function __construct(
        private PDO $connection
    )
$statement = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT (
            item.id, item.category_id,
            item_category.letter
FROM item
            LEFT OUTER JOIN item_category ON item_category.letter = item.category_id
WHERE item.id = :id
$statement->execute(['id' => $id]);
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: [See how PDO's fetch() work](https://phpize.online/s/L4). This is original PDO. Whatever gives you that "row" we don't know.

Comment: I understand that. I have 7 repositories. 6 of them use data from only 1 table. Everything works great, i get 
['column1'] => value1,
['column2'] => value2
etc.
But when i do the same things (literally the same) but JOINING other tables' columns I get this 
['row'] => (col1value,col2value,col3value....).
Same PDO, same variables, same functions. The only difference is JOIN

Comment: why there are braces in the query?

Comment: Sorry that's just me being dumb. Thank you very much for your time